# Flutter IOS Select TeamId

Tags: ios, flutter

I have a developer account with several teams inside.

Each team can build a unique Flutter(IOS Schema) application.

When I'm trying to make build via flutter commands it always picks up 1st team from my account, in that reason I have an error:

*No profile for team MY_FIRST_TEAM matching MY_PROFILE_FOR_CURRENT_APP found: Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching 'FIRST_TEAM/SECOND_PROFILE'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the Signing & Capabilities tab of the target editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')*

My flatter command:
 **flutter build ios --release --flavor FLAVOR -t MAIN.dart**

My Xcode signing & certificates tab setup correctly without any errors.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that worked for me was to run the failing command myself.

- Make sure you're in the iOS subdirectory.
- Run the failing Xcode command. For me, it looked like this:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -configuration "Release MyAppProfile" VERBOSE_SCRIPT_LOGGING=YES DEVELOPMENT_TEAM={CORRECT_DEVELOPMENT_TEAM} -allowProvisioningUpdates -allowProvisioningDeviceRegistration -workspace Runner.xcworkspace -scheme myScheme BUILD_DIR=MY_BUILD_DIR/build/ios -sdk iphoneos SCRIPT_OUTPUT_STREAM_FILE=/var/folders/4p/wtrd46612tdd27nmv6f18t7w0000gn/T/flutter_build_log_pipe.Z9PySO/pipe_to_stdout FLUTTER_SUPPRESS_ANALYTICS=true COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO
```